# Not able to boot from Windows USB on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, ubuntu, boot

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on a laptop running Ubuntu.

But the problem is, it's not booting from the USB.

Details:

- Tried formatting USB drive as FAT and NTFS.
- It get's detected in BIOS menu, so no issue with that, but after selecting that and hitting Enter, nothing happens. Just Ubuntu will load like normal.
- For testing purpose, if i create a linux bootable USB using same USB drive, it works, but not a Windows.
- one thing, Pressing **F2** does not open BIOS settings now. It used to work earlier when i had installed Windows.
  I wanted to see if it's using UEFI/ Legacy mode for booting, and wanted to change that.
- Tried Shutting down my laptop, holding F2, then turn on laptop, still it won't load BIOS settings.

I have tried several things told in many forums, nothing seems to work.

Please suggest something.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you changed the boot order?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. That doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: The problem must be in the way you've made the installation media and/or the ISO itself.

Comment: 1. "Pressing F2 does not open BIOS settings now." Can you get to BIOS through the grub menu at boot? Also, as others mention, make the boot USB device on a Windows machine using MS tool, http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=616447, for best chances of success. 3. Has the PC run Windows in the past, or do you have a license?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes. I had Windows 8 installed on it few years ago. Now i have lost the license key and the microsoft account associated with that. I have been using Ubuntu only from last 2 years. I have not tried creating USB device on a Windows machine yet, sound like it might work. I will try and update the result here. Thanks!

Comment: Unless the disk has been completely formatted since installing Ubuntu, you likely still have the key on the HDD. Also, look on the bottom of the PC for license number. Without a license, don't install Win 10: it will work for a month or two, and then lock so you no longer can use most features.

Comment: I don't think i can get the key now, the hard drive not only was formatted multiple times, also now it's damaged. But thanks for the information, will be useful for next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution and installed Windows 10.

It was because i was creating bootable USB with GPT scheme in my Ubuntu installed on the same laptop, and my BIOS is an old one, which works on MBR scheme.

So i formatted the USB in my macbook as a FAT parition & MBR scheme, then made the USB bootable, then i tried in my old laptop. Worked!